# Can't load glove.6B.300d.txt

Tags: word2vec

I'm trying to load glove vectors, with the following code

```
en_model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=False)
```

and I unexpectedly get the following error.

```
 File "/home/k/Desktop/Work/Vector explorer/word2vec-explorer/vec_test_loader.py", line 55, in make_model
en_model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(model_path, binary=is_bin)
 File "/home/k/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 1119, in load_word2vec_format
limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
 File "/home/k/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 175, in _load_word2vec_format
vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format
 File "/home/k/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py", line 175, in <genexpr>
vocab_size, vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split())  # throws for invalid file format

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'the'
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gensim need more information about `model_path`, we have to append two number at the first line which the first indicates how many numbers of words vocabulary we have and the second  indicates the number of dimension of word embedding, it looks like below:

```
101 300
the 1.0 2.1 -1.3 ...
I   1.1 0.2 -0.3 ...
.
.
.
```

you can try to use one line code as below:

```
python -m gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec --input  glove.840B.300d.txt --output glove.840B.300d.w2vformat.txt
```

Or you can use my code as reference below:

```
import gensim
import os
import shutil
import hashlib
from sys import platform

def getFileLineNums(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        count += 1
    return count


def prepend_line(infile, outfile, line):
    with open(infile, 'r') as old:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as new:
            new.write(str(line) + "\n")
            shutil.copyfileobj(old, new)

def prepend_slow(infile, outfile, line):
    with open(infile, 'r') as fin:
        with open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
            fout.write(line + "\n")
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line)

def load(filename):
    num_lines = getFileLineNums(filename)
    gensim_file = 'glove_model.txt'
    gensim_first_line = "{} {}".format(num_lines, 300)
    # Prepends the line.
    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
        prepend_line(filename, gensim_file, gensim_first_line)
    else:
        prepend_slow(filename, gensim_file, gensim_first_line)

    model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(gensim_file)
    return model
model = load(your_model_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we're only prepending a line with counts for the number of lines and the dimension count (length and width of the embeddings, so to speak) I used this quick script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Path to the GloVe file
GLOVE_FILE="path/to/glove.840B.300d.txt"

# Calculate the number of lines (words) in the GloVe file
NUM_LINES=$(wc -l < "$GLOVE_FILE")

# Embedding dimension (should match the dimension in the GloVe file)
EMBEDDING_DIM=300
    
# Extract the filename without the extension
FILENAME=$(basename "$GLOVE_FILE" .txt)

# Construct the new filename with "_w2vformat_bash" before the extension
NEW_FILE="${FILENAME}_w2vformat_bash.txt"

# Create a new file with the first line containing the number of lines and embedding dimension
echo "$NUM_LINES $EMBEDDING_DIM" | cat - "$GLOVE_FILE" > "$NEW_FILE"
```